# ORACLE 12c + PHP 5.6.13 (Win32) - cannot load php_pdo_oci.dll

Tags: php, windows, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

**Database-Server:** ORACLE 12c

**App-Server:** Windows NT SERVER1 6.3 build 9200 (Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition) i586

**Apache:** Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) PHP/5.6.13

**PHP:** php-5.6.13-Win32-VC11-x86

With this components I try to execute this small php script and get this warning:

```
<?php

    foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
      {
      echo $driver.'<br />';
      }  

?>

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Program Files (x86)/php-5.6.13-Win32-VC11-x86/ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Translation so far: **%1 is no allowable Win32-Application**

**Question:**
PHP 5.6.13 (Win32) cannot load the ext/php_pdo_oci.dll library because of "this ist no Win32-Application" ?

Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_php_oci8_with_32-bit_php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for close this question the solution.

**32-bit PHP needs 32-bit Oracle client**

To check what Oracle-Client is installed use TNSPING with this small windows script (CMD). **myoracledb** based on TNSNAMES.ORA entry.

```
tnsping myoracledb
pause
```

The result should something like this...

```
    TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 28-SEP-2015 10:51:44

    Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
[...]
```

..for **32-bit Windows** or ...for **64-bit Windows**